# Caught segfault (R crashes on launch)

Tags: r

I just installed R v. 3.2.0 on a Mac 10.10.2. It crashed immediately. Prior versions had worked fine. Here is the error code:

```
     *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
3: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =      vI[[j]])
4: asNamespace(ns)
5: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,      .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
6: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
7: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
8: loadNamespace(name)
9: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
10: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
11: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
12: tryCatch(loadNamespace(name), error = function(e) {    warning(gettextf("namespace %s is not available and has been replaced\nby  .GlobalEnv when processing object %s",         sQuote(name)[1L], sQuote(where)), domain = NA, call. = FALSE,         immediate. = TRUE)    .GlobalEnv})
13: ..getNamespace(c("ggplot2", "1.0.0"), "a")
14: load("/Users/rcampbell/.RData")
```

Comment: What happens if you rename or remove your workspace image `"/Users/rcampbell/.RData"`?

Comment: To clarify: I did not remove the workspace; I created a subdirectory. It's possible that removing the workspace would have worked but I thought the subdirectory was more promising.